# Technical name for an almost-monotonic function

Tags: functions, terminology

I'm wondering if there’s a technical name or short phrase that describes a function that’s monotonic, subject to some uniformly bounded amount of backtracking.

$\exists \epsilon \forall x , y : y \gt x \Rightarrow f(y) \gt f(x) - \epsilon $

A simple example of this would be if you start with any monotonic function and add a fixed amount of error, jitter or oscillation. Concretely, if our epsilon is 20, you’d have a function that, once it reaches 100, we know it will never drop to 80 (or less) again.

**Extra credit:** There's a similar form of near-monotonicity where the limit is on the function’s domain rather than the range. If this also has a name, I’d be curious to hear it—though the case I really care about is the one I described above.

This other form looks like this: $\exists \delta \forall x , y : y \gt x + \delta \Rightarrow f(y) \gt f(x)$

Comment: Alternative condition: There exists monotonic $g$ with $\|f-g\|_\infty\le\epsilon/2$